# Comparing two HTML strings

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, .net-core

I have a website that makes use of TinyMce. The `getcontent()` function of TinyMce returns the content of the TinyMce as a string, like for example:

```
<p>Test<img src="../../../files/a54f58ca-56e1-4e6a-acf5-1cccebe51dc1/FY17/img/21c17e0e-b433-42de-97c7-cf0194fc7ac4" /></p>
```

And if I try to get the content from the DOM I get the following HTML also as a string:

```
<p>Test<img src="/files/a54f58ca-56e1-4e6a-acf5-1cccebe51dc1/FY17/img/21c17e0e-b433-42de-97c7-cf0194fc7ac4"></p>
```

They are both the same HTML, just slightly different in how they are typed. I want to compare both strings and want to make sure that both are equal in terms of HTML, how would I accomplish this in C#?

I have been thinking to maybe use regex to match this, but I'm unsure if that's the proper approach.

Comment: Please specify your problem more clearly. You want to compare urls in the img src attribute or what? What do you mean by "equal in terms of HTML"?

Comment: yeah hard to know exactly what they want to compare.  The two have different HTML, the second has an unclosed image tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# string has a method Equals() that you can use to compare your strings.

```
   string a = "<p>Test<img src=\".. / .. / .. / files / a54f58ca - 56e1 - 4e6a - acf5 - 1cccebe51dc1 / FY17 / img / 21c17e0e - b433 - 42de - 97c7 - cf0194fc7ac4\" /></p>";
   string b = "<p>Test<img src=\"/files/a54f58ca-56e1-4e6a-acf5-1cccebe51dc1/FY17/img/21c17e0e-b433-42de-97c7-cf0194fc7ac4\"></p>";
   Console.WriteLine(b.Equals(a));
```

note, that you might need to modify your strings a bit. In example, HTML " have been replaced with \" so that they work in C# string.

Also, not sure is this what you where looking for. Question is a bit hazy.